# Correlation between 2 timeseries dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

I'm fairly new at python, and would like to perform correlation between 2 dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-01-04','2015-01-05','2015-01-06'],
                   'stockprice1':['1.01','1.01','1.01',],
                   'stockprice2':['1.04','1.05','1.03',]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-01-04','2015-01-05','2015-01-06'],
                   'variable1':['1.11','1.21','1.31',],
                   'variable2':['2.01','2.04','2.03',]})

result = df1.corrwith(df2)
```

My intended output would look something like a 2x2 display of the correlation coefficients (of stockprice vs. variable). However, the code below doesn't seem to work, does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi There please provide a text based data sample with your ideal output [mcve]. Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) question and answer to find out how to ask a good pandas question.

Comment: @Datanovice Hey sorry for that, i've revised my question to try to isolate the problem

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections,

1. `stockprice1` has 0 variance so the correlation between itself and other variables is going to be `NaN`.
2. [`corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) is used when the dataframes share the same column names which are not the case.
3. Correlations are for numeric type variables, here the variables are strings.

Solution: [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) as `float` all variables, then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both dataframes, use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html), and filter the matrix.

```
#change df1 so the correlations are no `NaN`
df1.stockprice1 = ['1.02', '1.09', '1.01']

df1[['stockprice1', 'stockprice2']] = df1[[
    'stockprice1', 'stockprice2']].astype(float)
df2[['variable1', 'variable2']] = df2[[
    'variable1', 'variable2']].astype(float)


correlations = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).corr().iloc[0:2, -2:]


#               variable1   variable2
# stockprice1   -0.114708   0.675845
# stockprice2   -0.500000   0.327327
```